# Show validation messages below the element with jquery unobtrusive in asp.net mvc3

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-javascript

I need to show the validation messages below the element.

I have tried adding the message like:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "<br /> UserName is required")]
public string UserName { get; set; }
```

But the above required message is rendered as (where the validation messages is encoded):

```
<input type="text" value="" tabindex="1" style="height:auto; width:280px;" size="40" name="UserName" maxlength="15" id="UserName" data-val-required="&amp;lt;br /&amp;gt; UserName is required" data-val="true" class="textfield">
```

[image: Validation Message]

If i remove the `<br/>` from the message of the Model, the validation message shows in two lines. Also i have tried adding the validation as below, but the validation message is not overriden as in the below validate method (overriding from "UserName is required" to "Enter username"):

```
$('#userSignInform').validate({
    rules:
        {
            UserName: { required: true },
            Password: { required: true }
        },
    messages:
        {
            UserName: { required: "Enter Username" },
            Password: { required: "Enter the Password" }
        },
    errorPlacement: function (error, element)
        {
            error.appendTo(element.parent("td").next("td"));
        }
});
```

Whats the workaround need to be done to show the validation messages below the element and to override the model message with the jquery validate method?

Answer (score 10):

Validation message markup is generated as:

```html
<span class="field-validation-error" data-valmsg-for="UserName" data-valmsg-replace="true">
     <span for="UserName" generated="true" class="">UserName is required</span>
</span>
```

As you see, it has got class `field-validation-error`. Just add up simple css to display validation message on new line

```css
.field-validation-error {
    display: block;
}
```

And the validation messages will be displayed of the second line.

If you want this placement applied only to specific messages, just change class selector to be more specific.

Comment: archil, The message shows below the element perfectly. Any workaround on how to change the validation message with jquery validate method?

Comment: $('#UserName').rules("add", {
 messages: {
   required: "Required input",
 }
}); This is documented at http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/rules#overview

Comment: archil, that worked perfect for customizing the error message. Can we customize the validate method to show in new line instead of css fix?

Comment: As documented, you should use errorPlacement, as you already do.

Comment: I have tried it and its not working when i have unobtrusive validation enabled.

Comment: You should debug that. For example, have you got those textboxes inside table?

Comment: Its working when i remove the unobtrusive validation reference. Its not working only when i have unobtrusive validation. Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

Just add `<br/>` in html.

Eg:

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName, "User Name 1")
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)<br />
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)
```